# How to format currency in Oracle SQL Developer 19.4.0?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using SQL developer in one of my database classes and I have homework where certain formatting is needed. When I use the commands given by the professor on my SQL Developer I get an error

Here are the commands:

```
col price format $99,990.99
col quoted_price format $99,990.99
col balance format $99,990.99
col credit_limit format 99,990.99
```

The errors I get are:

```
SP2-0246: Illegal FORMAT string "$99,"
SP2-0246: Illegal FORMAT string "$99,"
SP2-0246: Illegal FORMAT string "$99,"
SP2-0246: Illegal FORMAT string "99,"
```

When I run these same commands on the lab computer it works but the lab uses an outdated version of SQL developer. It's version 4.1.1

Would appreciate any help

The homework is asks us to input a command that would display query results for example a question would be "x" situation

My command will be:

```sql
SELECT item_num, price, description, balance
from item;
```

The query output below will have $ if needed and will have the commas and periods.

Comment: are you trying to store this data in a table ? which datatype you are storing as ? If you mention your final output of what you are trying to do that will be helpful

Comment: Are they teaching you with SQLPlus? We support some of those COL format commands, but not all of them. Also, v4.1 is very very old...

Comment: Are your column types are alpha-numeric (i.e. VARCHAR2) instead of just numeric (NUMBER)? Maybe it's trying to put a letter against that format string which I would imagine is an issue.

Comment: I'm not trying to store in on a table. I'm formatting it so that when I run commands like

SELECT item_num, price, description

from item;

the output in the query would be correct with dollar signs if needed.

Comment: Thatjeffsmith no were not learning SQLPlus but SQL developer

Answer (score 2):

If you are storing salary as Number, then you can use to_char(column,'$9,999.99');

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE EMP
  2  (EMPNO NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
  3   ENAME VARCHAR2(10),
  4   JOB VARCHAR2(9),
  5   MGR NUMBER(4),
  6   HIREDATE DATE,
  7   SAL NUMBER(7, 2),
  8   COMM NUMBER(7, 2),
  9   DEPTNO NUMBER(2)
 10  );

SQL> INSERT INTO EMP VALUES (7369, 'SMITH',  'CLERK',     7902,TO_DATE('17-DEC-1980', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),  800, NULL, 20);

SQL> select ename, to_char( sal, '$9,999.99' ) "Salary" from emp;

ENAME      Salary
---------- ----------
SMITH         $800.00
```

Comment: I'm not trying to store a number as a salary. The homework is about getting the data from tables we already have in the database. 

For example: If the questions asks for something and the answer is SELECT item_num, price, description, balance
from item;

Then the output on the bottom will have the dollar sign, comma and period as opposed to none when the formatting isn't used

Comment: okay, what is the data type of column which you are trying to format?

Comment: I am not sure if we can format varchar type column with below command
COLUMN SAL FORMAT $99,990
I read the documentation, they have given only below example for varchar type column
COLUMN ENAME FORMAT A4